# How to validate html response body in cypress for API testing

Tags: cypress

I have been testing an API. Now I am getting the API response in HTML format where I have table data (without table name) and under the  i have ahref tag and test. I have to validate the ahref text fro the response body.

So anyone has any idea that will really helpful for me.

I tried:

```js
cy.wrap(res.body).get('table').contains('td','textname')
```

but getting timeout error.

Comment: Please add the html response that you are getting to the question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use JavaScript's `DOMParser` to parse your string into a DOM variable.

```js
it('tests something', () => {
  // Declare the DOMParser
  const parser = new DOMParser();
  cy.request('/foo').then((res) => {
    // Parse the string (in this case, the response body) as a `text/html` object.
    const dom = parser.parseFromString(res.body, 'text/html');
    // use document functions below to traverse the dom
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To test the HTML from response with Cypress commands, you need to write and visit it so that Cypress thinks it's a legit web page

```js
cy.writeFile('./cypress/fixtures/fragment.html', html)
  .then(() => {            // writing is async so wait for it to complete

    cy.visit('./cypress/fixtures/fragment.html')
    cy.get('table').contains('td','textname')
  })
```

Should be done in a separate `it()` block to avoid conflicts with you main app page.

Otherwise you can follow @agoff's pattern and use `dom.querySelector()` to query the data.

Comment: Hello Fody. Thanks for your response. But when I tried the above method I am getting a failed error message. cy.find() failed because it requires a DOM element.

Comment: Ok, the problem is in the `cy.wrap()` - let me see what can be done.